# Markup for amusing, non-factual content

Tags: seo, schema.org, technical-seo

On a webpage with factual information, I'd like to add a 'Did you know' box with an amusing, non-factual piece of text; a little joke to add a bit of flair to the page.

However, I intend this page to rank well in search, and I'd like to make it clear to search engines that this piece of info is intended for amusement rather than factual accuracy.

I'm thinking to use schema.org markup for this as follows:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ClaimReview">
  <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Thing">
    <span itemprop="name">Chicken Wire Fences History</span>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="claimReviewed">
    <p>Chicken wire fences have a rich history dating back thousands of years. They were originally used by ancient civilizations such as the Romans and Greeks, who recognized the need for both protection and ventilation for their chickens. These early chicken wire fences were often made of wood or fabric and featured intricate designs and patterns.</p>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="false">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <span itemprop="name">My Website Name</span>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="datePublished" content="2023-06-01"></div>
</div>
<p>PS: While this piece of information may not hold up to historical scrutiny, there's no denying the practical elegance and modern appeal of chicken wire fences.</p>
```

Is this a good approach? Will search engines understand the intent of this part of the page?

Comment: Too bad `<satire></satire>` tags aren't real.  I highly doubt that there is any markup that will cause search engines truth analysis machine learning algorithms to ignore a section of the page.  Have you considered hiding this portion of the page from search engines entirely?

Comment: Haha, I love that idea of the `<satire>` tag. Hiding that part altogether is also an idea. I had a quick look around and it seems I could do that with an iframe that's no-index.